# Как скрыть полосу прокрутки в body?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, плагин, lightbox

Установлен плагин [Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) на сайте, для вывода iframe. Как можно убрать полосу прокрутки основного сайта, т.е body. Вот [демо](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/)
, в нём пятая снизу ссылка на iframe.

Comment: Вот пример сделал [ссылка](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGBxme)

Comment: У body или html могут быть margin и padding. Они дают прокрутку, если какой-то элемент использует размер в 100% от body

Comment: Надо убрать прокрутку у всего сайта, когда включается всплывающее окно с iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позвольте одолжить вам свой костыль, мсьё

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".iframe").colorbox({
    iframe: true,
    width: "95%",
    height: "87%",
    fixed: "false"
  });
  $(".iframe").click(function() {
    $("body").attr("style", "overflow:hidden;");
  });
  $("#cboxOverlay").click(function() {
    $("body").attr("style", "overflow:visible;");
  });
});
```

CSS

```
#colorbox,
#cboxOverlay,
#cboxWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2058;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#cboxWrapper {
  max-width: none;
}

#cboxOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#cboxMiddleLeft,
#cboxBottomLeft {
  clear: left;
}

#cboxContent {
  position: relative;
}

#cboxLoadedContent {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#cboxTitle {
  margin: 0;
}

#cboxLoadingOverlay,
#cboxLoadingGraphic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#cboxPrevious,
#cboxNext,
#cboxClose,
#cboxSlideshow {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cboxPhoto {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  max-width: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.cboxIframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
}

#colorbox,
#cboxContent,
#cboxLoadedContent {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}

#cboxOverlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#colorbox {
  outline: 0;
}

#cboxTopLeft {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url("../images/controls.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

#cboxTopCenter {
  height: 14px;
  background: url("../images/border.png") repeat-x top left;
}

#cboxTopRight {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url("../images/controls.png") no-repeat -36px 0;
}

#cboxBottomLeft {
  width: 14px;
  height: 43px;
  background: url("../images/controls.png") no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

#cboxBottomCenter {
  height: 43px;
  background: url("../images/border.png") repeat-x bottom left;
}

#cboxBottomRight {
  width: 14px;
  height: 43px;
  background: url("../images/controls.png") no-repeat -36px -32px;
}

#cboxMiddleLeft {
  width: 14px;
  background: url("../images/controls.png") repeat-y -175px 0;
}

#cboxMiddleRight {
  width: 14px;
  background: url("../images/controls.png") repeat-y -211px 0;
}

#cboxContent {
  background: #000;
  overflow: visible;
}

.cboxIframe {
  background: #000;
}

#cboxError {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#cboxLoadedContent {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#cboxLoadingOverlay {
  background: url("../images/loading_background.png") no-repeat center center;
}

#cboxLoadingGraphic {
  background: url("../images/loader.gif") no-repeat center center;
}

#cboxTitle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #7C7C7C;
  text-shadow: none;
}

#cboxCurrent {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 58px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #7C7C7C;
  text-shadow: none;
}

#cboxPrevious,
#cboxNext,
#cboxSlideshow,
#cboxClose {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -29px;
  background: url("../images/controls.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#cboxPrevious:active,
#cboxNext:active,
#cboxSlideshow:active,
#cboxClose:active {
  outline: 0;
}

#cboxPrevious {
  left: 0px;
  background-position: -51px -25px;
}

#cboxPrevious:hover {
  background-position: -51px 0px;
}

#cboxNext {
  left: 27px;
  background-position: -75px -25px;
}

#cboxNext:hover {
  background-position: -75px 0px;
}

#cboxClose {
  right: 0;
  background-position: -100px -25px;
}

#cboxClose:hover {
  background-position: -100px 0px;
}

.cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow {
  background-position: -125px 0px;
  right: 27px;
}

.cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow:hover {
  background-position: -150px 0px;
}

.cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow {
  background-position: -150px -25px;
  right: 27px;
}

.cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow:hover {
  background-position: -125px 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/" class="iframe" style="height:1000px;position:absolute">Демо</a>
```

В местном интерпретаторе чего-то не воспроизводится так, как на codepen.

[Вот ссылка на codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvLqYq)

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!!!